# Magento 1: Load failed with status 404 for script ‘https://mywebsite/sp-push-worker.js

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting this error message, why this is coming nowadays suddenly I didn't understand.
Error:
Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope ‘https://mywebsite/’: Load failed with status 404 for script ‘https://mywebsite/sp-push-worker.js’

Comment: any suggestion to figured out why am I unable to load (404) ?